# AES Decryption in Java Not Returning the Same String as the Plaintext

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to create a program in java in which part of it uses AES encryption to encrypt data for my final project in a coding class. Here is the code that I am using for my encryption:

```
static String symmetric(String info, String key, String mode) {
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        byte [] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Crypto.sha256(key));
        byte [] information = Base64.getDecoder().decode(info);
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "AES");

        if (mode.equals("ENCRYPT")) {
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        } else if (mode.equals("DECRYPT")) {
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
        }
            
        return (Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(c.doFinal(information)).trim());
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    return (null);
}
```

When I encrypt my data using `String ciphterText = symmetric("message", "key", "ENCRYPT")` and decrypt the ciphertext using `symmetric(cipherText, "key", "DECRYPT")`, the string it returns is `"messagc="`. I'm worried that the padding is weird but I don't know how to fix it.

**FYI:** `Crypto.sha256(String input)` is a method I created that returns the sha256 hash of info as a base 64 string. Here is the code for it if it helps:

```
public static String sha256(String input) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte [] tempHash = digest.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        return (Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tempHash));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }

    return (null);
}
```

**Also** I know ECB is not secure compared to other methods that use initialization vectors, but it is a small project and I don't have enough time to do that, which is the same reason why I'm not salting my hashes. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Because you implement encryption and decryption together, you inadmissibly mix the various encodings/decodings. E.g. you Base64 decode the passed data. This makes sense for decryption, but not for encryption, where a UTF-8 encoding would make sense. A possible solution is to pass and return the data as `byte[]` and do the encoding/decoding outside your function.

Comment: So would it make more sense to just do every operation using `byte []`  through UTF-8 encoding (with string), then converting to base64 or hexadecimal only when writing to the files that I am using to store everything?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the way you are using base-64 encoding.

When you encrypt, you are treating "message" as base-64 encoded bytes. The last block is "age". A strict decoder would reject that input, because it is missing padding, and has some extra bits that spill over into the third byte. But a permissive decoder ignores that, and decodes the array as `{ 0x99, 0xeb, 0x2c, 0x6a, 0x07 }`

The correct base-64 encoding of `{ 0x99, 0xeb, 0x2c, 0x6a, 0x07 }` is "messagc=".

To make this work correctly, every statement in your method should differ depending on the mode flag. It would be more clear and clean to separate encrypt and decrypt methods.

Comment: That makes sense, from being in so deep I didn't even realize that my code was treating the message as base64... I guess we all make mistakes.